# Select columns from function call in sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

In postgresql I have `select col1, col2 from my_function()`. How can I do that in sqlalchemy core?

`select(func.my_function())` gives the result as a string, but I want a tuple.

Comment: It tends not to play nicely with SPs, I remember giving up on this and running raw commands.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use [`FunctionElement.alias()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias) and the light weight [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column):

```
from sqlalchemy import func, select, column

stmt = select([column('col1'), column('col2')]).\
    select_from(func.my_function().alias())
```

The documentation specifically mentions Postgresql as a use case for this construct. The above produces:

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM my_function() AS anon_1
```

Using the parameter *_selectable* of `column()` you could also:

```
In [4]: fn = func.my_function().alias()

In [5]: stmt = select([column('col1', _selectable=fn),
   ...:                column('col2', _selectable=fn)])

In [6]: print(stmt)
SELECT anon_1.col1, anon_1.col2 
FROM my_function() AS anon_1
```

but since *_selectable* is left undocumented, this might not be a good idea.