# How to join subquery results to function results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to write a query like this:

```
SELECT
    hour,
    avg(value)
from
    generate_series('2019-10-01T00:00:00'::timestamp, '2019-10-01T23:00:00'::timestamp, '0 days 3600.000000 seconds'::interval) AS hour
left outer join
    (
        select
            *
        from
            data
        where
            parent_id=10 and
            date_time >= '2019-10-01T00:00:00'::timestamp and
            date_time < '2019-10-02T00:00:00'::timestamp
    ) "inn" on date_trunc('hour', inn.date_time) = hour
group by
    hour
order by
    hour;
```

My data table has 3 columns, parent_id, date_time and value.

I've spend few hours already and there's no way I can get it to work exactly like above.

The closest I've got (at least semantically it make sense) is:

```
series = func.generate_series(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
).label('hour')

subquery = (
    session
    .query(data)
    .filter(data.parent_id == parent_id)
    .filter(data.date_time >= start_date)
    .filter(data.date_time < end_date)
    .subquery()
)

query = (
    session
    .query(
        series
    )
    .outerjoin(
        subquery,
        func.date_trunc('hour', subquery.c.reading_date_time) == series
    )
)
```

But its not working, it's not possible to reference "hour" column like this, the error I get is `Don't know how to join to SELECT` (I skip code for group by because it's not an issue here)

Comment: Instead of `label()` you need `FunctionElement.alias()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130990/select-columns-from-function-call-in-sqlalchemy-core

Comment: Tried that, but its not working. If I get alias of generate_series and do just session.query(alias), it fails as it tries to do something like

SELECT anon_1.generate_series_1 AS anon_1_generate_series_1 from generate_series() as anon_1. 

It doesnt work as there's no such thing as generate_series_1. It should be just select anon_1.

Comment: If you read the linked Q/A carefully, you'll note that instead of using the alias object other than in `select_from()` or joins, use `column()` constructs to refer to the columns produced by the table valued function. It'd be nice if it worked the way you attempted, or something close, but for now we have to settle.

Comment: @IljaEverilä gotcha, thanks. I got it working, if you're interested in bounty you can create answer by yourself, otherwise I will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Ilja's tips, I got it working:

```
series = func.generate_series(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
).alias('hour')

subquery = (
    session
    .query(data)
    .filter(data.point_id == point_id)
    .filter(data.date_time >= start_date)
    .filter(data.date_time < end_date)
    .subquery()
)

r = (
    session
    .query(
        column('hour'),
        func.avg(subquery.c.value).label('avg')
    )
    .select_from(series)
    .outerjoin(
        subquery,
        func.date_trunc('hour', subquery.c.date_time) == column('hour')
    )
    .group_by(column('hour'))
    .order_by(column('hour'))
)
```