# tag search on postgres via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to query a tags column (currently modelled as a character varying array). I would like to find any rows in which the tags column contains the query string as a left anchored substring, and would like to do so using sqlalchemy. My research has led me to learn about different ways of optimizing text search, but several lookup message still require usage of 'unnest'. I am open to changing the column from character varying array to something else (or having a separate, related table for tags), but am also curious on using unnest in sqlalchemy.

eg.

```
SELECT * FROM batches, UNNEST(tags) t WHERE t like 'poe%';
```

works and will find a row where tags column is ['math', 'poetry'].

I haven't found the right way to use unnest in sqlalchemy's python orm. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130990/select-columns-from-function-call-in-sqlalchemy-core